# How to use firebase authentication in couchbase sync gateway

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I'm developing an Android app. I have used firebase(email, password) authentication mechanism which is very secure and easy to implement. And as I want the data to be stored in our servers, I'm not using firebase storage. Couchbase sync gateway supports any open ID authentication. But I'm finding difficult integrating both. I have been searching more than a week. Anyone who have already used it. Could you please help me configuring.

Comment: alerted my colleagues leading Couchbase mobile technologies.. they will respond.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Have you read this? https://blog.couchbase.com/2016/august/couchbase-mobile-v1.3-openid-connect

Comment: The question pertains to [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/). Apps and Web can use Firebase Authentication to know the identity of a user. It is a very simple way to easily implement robust authentication. 

The question is can Couchbase Sync Gateway [verify](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) Firebase ID Tokens?

@Hod

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer, here are the steps to do it:

- Firebase sends you an id_token (not signed). I assume you got to this part.
- You convert this unsigned firebase id_token to a signed 3rd party oidc id_token. I use Keycloak running lightweight in a docker container for this job. Remember, you want the id_token, not access_token.

[image]

- (Optional) you use Sync Gateway (SGW) ADMIN REST end point to create an user and assign the user to his/her appropriate [admin_channels].
- SGW will accept your Keycloak signed oidc and give you a cookie when you hit its REST interface at the /_session end point. Make sure you put the id_token string in the Authorization header in the format "Bearer id_token_string........".

A few notes:

- SGW will use the username (or create a new one if none existed) based on the "username_claim" keyword definition in your SGW.json config file. Use Keycloak client's mappers function if you want to customize your SGW user's name.
- If you want to get the user's id_token without having to know the user's password then use the experimental token-exchange feature as mentioned here. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65714161/keycloak-generate-access-token-for-a-user-with-keycloak-admin).

[image]

[image]

- You use this cookie information to connect and sync data with couchbase via SGW as usual.

Couchbase has an article on how to implement implicit flow for oidc using syncgateway [source](https://developer.couchbase.com/tutorial-syncgateway-openid-auth)